# Windows 7 Search

Tags: search

How can I customize windows 7 Search to find a text string in a cell in Microsoft Excel 2013 workbook files?

I have tried many ways but it does not open specific files with the specific text string that I am looking for.

**Example:**

All the excel files I want to search are on a memory stick; lets say K:\ tourmakeady (root folder) Tourmakeady has a sub folder called "Owenbrin". Owenbrin in turn has a number of sub folders one which is named "Cummer". Now there is an excel file in this folder with the name "Mary Casey" in one cell or maybe in more than one cell. My question is: How do I locate the name "Mary Casey" from windows 7 search box. I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: Why not open the 13 files in excel at the same time and perform the search there?

Comment: It's "excel version13" I meant. the files are in different folders.

Comment: I've edited your question so the text is more understrandable.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use Windows Search rather than just opening the file in Excel and searching that way?

Comment: The number of excel files is too large and they are in different folders.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing this in the search bar of the root folder: **type: FileFormat SearchString**, where FileFormat is either *xls* or *xlsx*.

Comment: Still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows Search, you can use keywords such as `type` and `kind` to select specific file types to search.  In the search box, to find the word **product** and only in Excel files, you can put this

```
type:xlsx product
```

This will find only files that match the `.xlsx` file type.  This won't target explicitly the 2013 versions, but it will find only 2007 and higher versions of Excel files.

**Addendum based on example:**

First, be aware that USB drives are not typically indexed by Windows Search, and non-indexed locations can't usually find text within a file.  You can enable it, but I have not had much success with that.  To enable looking within files, you will need to make sure that non-indexed locations have **File contents** enabled:

[image]

With that enabled, you can start by viewing the root of the **K:** drive and in the search box put `type:xlsx Mary Casey` and that should show you all the files where that name exists.  If you know one or more of the parent folders where the file should be (say, *Tourmakeady*) then you can navigate there before beginning the search.  Running the search from `K:\Tourmakeady` will be faster than from the root because it will limit to that folder and sub-folders.  Again, this may not work (probably will not work) on a USB drive.  Doing this from a hard drive that has been indexed by Windows Search will work and should be relatively quick.

Comment: Still no solution with this problem. Have you any further solutions to add and thanks for your time and patience with me.

Comment: @PatLardner What doesn't work about this solution?  If you have more details about your question, edit it so we can know.  Because this works on my machine for exactly what you asked: finding a text string in multiple Excel files.  It will look through all the folders on your computer if you start at the root of the drive.

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me so promptly. All the excel files I want to search are on a memory stick; lets say K:\ tourmakeady (root folder)   Tourmakeady has a sub folder called "Owenbrin". Owenbrin in turn has a number of sub folders one which is named "Cummer". Now there is an excel file in this folder with the name "Mary Casey" in one cell or maybe in more than one cell. My question is: How do I locate the name "Mary Casey" from windows 7 search box. I am using Excel 2013.

Comment: Sorry but these instructions do not solve my problem. I even copied the folder "Tourmakeady" onto my hard disk and went through all the indexing again. All it did was bring up a number of excel files and not ones with Mary Casey. I typed in the following in the windows search box "type:xlsx Mary Casey"

Comment: Please don't abandon me as there has to be a relatively easy solution to my query. Anyone help?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. When I search files on my machine in the manner I suggested, it just works. The only other alternative I could suggest is writing VBA to loop thru all folders, then files then worksheets and look for the text. Not particularly hard code, mostly just a lot of loops and file system access, but it's something you'd have to write on your own and come back for help if you get stuck.

Comment: Can you give me line by line instructions again as I must be missing some setting which should be changed.

Comment: i will just have to give up trying as nothing I have tried works. you did your best and thank you for your patience. it is however, something that excel and windows should be able to achieve and it's the first time excel has failed to provide answers.